# Remove text with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I want to remove a link from a page, but I also want to get rid of the text, not just the hyper-link.

```
<a class="std3" href="https://PDF/ashx?id=RDE2NTM5NDN8UzIxN3wxfDE1Sg==" target="_blank">(PDF)</a>
```

How can I remove this with greasemonkey creating a script?

Comment: Have you tried anything already or just asking us to do it for you?  If you have then please post your existing code.

Comment: I have a code for doing other things, but not sure how to remove a line completely. I know how to replace words, but not removing something entirely.

Comment: Could i use: var elmDeleted = document.getElementById("ads");
 elmDeleted.parentNode.removeChild(elmDeleted);

Chanding ads to std3?

Comment: That looks for elements by ID, but the link you want to remove does not have one.  You could remove it by searching for the class name,  but that will also remove anything else on the page that uses the same class name.  Without further info that would be bad advice.

Comment: Yeah there are two other links that use the same class name

Comment: I understand i could use jquery i think, and use this code to leave the first one and remove the rest.

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.trSkillCls').not(':first').remove();
});

But I'm unsure how jquery differs from normal creating a script in grease monkey.

Comment: Adding jQuery *may* make it easier, but it may also be overkill.  Finding one element on the page and then removing it doesn't require a whole library.  Will the link definitely always have the class `std3` and the text `(PDF)`?

Comment: Ah i done it with jquery. This is fun haha! Might have found a career i could actually be interested in. Are there any good websites you can link me to with regards to learning javascript and other similar things?

Comment: Well done :) . Just be aware of what I said about other elements with the same class.  The best way for you to learn is to just use it.  Keep going with things that you want to do and learning what you need along the way.  Also, avoid w3schools.  StackOverflow will have nearly everything you can think of anyway, and if not then you can always ask.  Good luck, and enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

Remove element with the help of class name:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("std3");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Remove element with the help of id: (Recommended)

```
var elem = document.getElementById("elementId");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

It will remove element completely from your page.

Comment: There's no method with the name `getElementByClassName`.  Also, his use of Greasemonkey makes it very clear that he has no control over the initial page content, so suggesting use of an ID is irrelevant to this question.